# Windows 7 screen not displayed after installing Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, grub, grub2

I bought a new Lenovo laptop with DOS and I wanted to make it dual boot (Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7, both 64 bit).

I took the following steps to install both systems:

- Installed Windows 7 OS
- Windows 7 working fine
- Installed Ubuntu 14.04
- On restart Boot menu is shown (Ubuntu, Adavanced, Memory, Windows..)
- On selecting Ubuntu, it is working fine

Here are my observations on selecting Windows after installation:

1. Boot menu disappears
2. The blank grub screen remains there
3. Windows 7 boots up (screen is still blank, but I hear the welcome sound of windows)
4. Screen is still blank, I enter the windows password and Windows log on (windows login sound is heard)
5. Screen still blank, I press Alt + F4, Enter, machine shuts down

I don't understand why the welcome screen on Windows 7 does not show up, even when both operating systems are installed successfully.

I tried the same again with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 and got the same results.

Here is the output of the `sudo lshw -C display` command:

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 0b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:62 memory:c0000000-c03fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

Comment: can anybody help me?

Comment: I have the exact same problem :(

Comment: Did you manage to solve it yet ?

Comment: No. I used wubi.